# Wall Shelves mounted on wood in garage

Tags: walls, garage, mounting, adhesive, shelving

I want to take the ugly standing shelves in my garage to place wall shelves up and give me floor space back and make the garage look nicer. The previous owner put a lot of screws in the that wall, which is cement.

The idea was to use a polyurethane construction adhesive or sealant to "glue" wood panels or plywood to the cement/cinderblock wall. Then screw in the wall shelves through the wood board.

I have a similar idea in mind for inside the house, only using an adhesive for wood against drywall because the drywall isn't very thick, and I don't have confidence in a sturdy wall shelf unless it's a no drill type (which I can't find for the diameter needed).

The items that will go on these shelves in the garage are various cleaning tools, paint cans, paint accessories, sport items, car wash items, car vac, etc.

The garage holds one car year-round, and another during bad storms. We're in Florida. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Trusting adhesive only to hold weight is usually not a good idea.  I would screw the plywood/wood into the blocks with cement anchors and put up the shelves.  Drywall usually has nice handy wood studs behind it, perfect for driving screws into.

Comment: If you want to avoid dealing with the concrete (glue alone is a bad idea, but drilling the concrete is easy with the right tool), consider lag screwing support framing to the ceiling and suspending the shelves. They can look really nice with 1/4" or 3/8" threaded rods hanging down to support the shelves.

Comment: Are you able to fasten boards to the floor and the ceiling with hardware, and fasten your shelves to the boards?  That would be way better than gluing panels to the wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a concrete garage wall, you want your shelf anchors to go through the surface-mounted plywood into the concrete behind it. On an interior drywall wall, you want your shelf anchors to go through the drywall into studs. This is even more important if you're putting heavy things on the shelves: tools, paint cans, car wash items, vacuums.

Shelves can be mounted with diagonal bracing from the bottom of the shelf to the wall, or held from above by rafters or ceiling joists; but again, you want these bracing members to go through drywall to the framing itself for extra support.

Surface mounting shelves that will hold heavy items above a car is not a good idea.